# Installing hard disk drive that has windows 8.1 to laptop previously had windows 7

Tags: desktop-computer

I had a laptop installed with windows 8.1 and its motherboard went dead.
Now i want to use that hard disk to another laptop that was previously installed windows 7.
Is it possible or what will be requirement for that hard disk to work.

Comment: If 8.1 was OEM, you can't move it to another computer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8.1 uses UEFI mode by default unless when installed in BIOS machines. Windows 7 was typically installed in Legacy/BIOS mode even in UEFI machines. As such, if the laptop that previously had Windows 7 installed is UEFI - regardless of the mode Windows 7 was installed - it may work*. **If BIOS it won't.**
The hardware itself - HDD - can be re-purposed for a new installation but the currently installed Windows 8.1 won't boot in an older BIOS machine.

- Make sure UEFI only is selected at the firmware settings. Now, depending on the hardware differences the "old" Windows 8.1 may not boot correctly in which case Windows installation media should be used to boot from an perform a repair. Additional drivers may also be required once the Windows boots successfully. Also it requires reactivation when it detects different hardware. *Depending on how different that hardware is, the activation might not be successful, since it might mistake this as an attempt at piracy*, from @computercarguy comment.

Comment: They might also have to reactivate Windows, since it's running different hardware.  Depending on how different that hardware is, the activation might not be successful, since it might mistake this as an attempt at piracy.

Comment: @computercarguy Thanks, forgot that part and it's huge so... Included the activation issue with your own comment, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Glad I could help!